# Running Apple instruments for Automation from Terminal

Tags: ios, automation, terminal, instruments

How can I run apple instruments for iOS automation (iPhone/iPad) from the command line? I saw some blogs which said the below command

```
instruments -w -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -e UIASCRIPT
```

I have not been able to get this running.

- Has anyone got this running?
- Can you please share the steps if you are running it from terminal already?

Answer (score 3):

Broken out by parameter for easier reading:

```
mkdir TestResults

instruments
-D TestResults/TestTrace/theTrace.trace 
-t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate 
/Absolute/Path/to/built/app/For/Simulator/AppName.app
-e UIARESULTSPATH TestResults/ 
-e UIASCRIPT Tests/some_test_file.js
```

Comment: I tried running the above command .But Insutruments failed to run .It threw the below error:

Comment: Instruments[94502:60f] -[NSAlert alertWithError:] called with nil NSError. A generic error message will be displayed, but the user deserves better.
Wed Feb  8 14:48:16 c1dev-dm23409.overstock.com instruments[94502] <Error>: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetCurrentCursorLocation: Invalid connection
Wed Feb  8 14:48:16 c1dev-dm23409.overstock.com instruments[94502] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.2012-02-08 14:48:16.137 [94502:60f] Recording cancelled : At least one target failed to launch; aborting run
Have you seen this>

Comment: I have seen that. Make sure the folders exist for the output directories specified in the `-D` and `-e UIARESULTSPATH` flags. Also, make sure that there's no existing file where you pointed the `-D` flag.

Comment: I rechecked the command that I gave , folders exist for the output directories specified in -D and -e flags and no file exists in D flag path . I am not able to figure out anything from the stack trace either.

Comment: Yeah, it's picky and fragile. But I've definitely been using the above command (with appropriate paths substituted) with Xcode 4.2.1. Note that the current Xcode 4.3 beta has issues with UIAutomation at the moment, so if you're using that, try 4.2.

Comment: My version details are as below :  Version: 4.2 (4C199)
  Location: /Developer
  Applications:
  Xcode: 4.2 (828) .Can you please compare this with yours.
  Instruments: 4.2 (4233)
  Dashcode: 3.0.2 (336)
  SDKs:
  Mac OS X:
  10.6: (10K549)
  iPhone OS:
  5.0: (9A334)
  iPhone Simulator:
  4.3: (8H7)
  5.0: (9A334)

Comment: nice one... i wonder how to select different simulator.. ie; iPhone retina (4-inch) iPad Retina and ipad Retina(64-bit)? would be really helpful if you add it to the solution